# Query about copying from 1 vector into another vector in Clojure

Tags: loops, clojure, copying

I am implementing merge sort in Clojure. Using my Java reference point, I need to create the equivalent of

```
for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
            aux[k] = a[k]; 
}
```

in Clojure.

Here is what I have already tried:

1. Loop and recur which don't seem to look quite like a 'for' loop, leading me to believe that the functional approach would be something radically different.
2. I also looked at the "for" macro which seems the closest to what I need, but the fact that jumped so many hoops to get to it, somehow makes me feel that I am not doing something the Clojure way.
3. I started with something like 
   `(defn copy-vector [a aux] (doseq [k a] (swap! aux conj k)))`.

But that seems horribly complicated for something that should be simple and is probably not even doing what I need it to it EXACTLY. Any inputs/guidance on the Clojure way of doing this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to copy a vector for? Copying a vector is trivial, but vectors are immutable so you don't need to make a copy. Do you want to copy a slice of a vector? That's also trivial.

Comment: Data in Clojure is immutable, so you can't _copy_ Clojure vector like you do it in imperative languages.

Comment: @DiegoBasch - Thanks for the reply. I think I understand that the vector is immutable, but that is about it. My intent is to copy everything to an auxiliary array, divide it into two halves, sort the two halves, and then merge back to the original. The Java code I referenced is a part of the merge method shown at the following link: [MergeSort](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/22mergesort/Merge.java.html)

Comment: To copy a vector use function vec.  For instance if you got a vector v then (vec v) creates a new vector which is a copy of v.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some mergesort implementations in Clojure.

[Spoiler warning: these are complete implementations.  If you want to work through it yourself you might not want to look at these straight away.]

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23627/mergesort-implementation-in-clojure

https://gist.github.com/alco/2135276
(This second one includes links to several other implementations.)